# How to create a working identifier for the cells of this table?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to give each cell of a table an identifier like in this photo [image: I'm sorry about this lol]

this is what I tried but it's not working:

```
function init() {
    var board = document.createElement('table');
    board.setAttribute("border", 1);
    board.setAttribute("cellspacing", 0);
    board.setAttribute("id", 'tbl');

    var identifier = 0;// <-------
    for (var i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        board.appendChild(row);
        for (var j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.setAttribute('height', 20);
            cell.setAttribute('width', 20);
            cell.classList.add('col' + j, 'row' + i);
            cell.identifier = identifier; // <-------
            row.appendChild(cell);
            identifier += identifier;// <--------this is the problem
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(board);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, instead of custom properties you should use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and instead of the `width` and `height` attributes you should use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). Second, you were incrementing `identifier` by itself, so it wouldn't grow from 0.

```js
const GRID_SIZE = 6;

function init() {
    var board = document.createElement('table');
    board.setAttribute("border", 1);
    board.setAttribute("cellspacing", 0);
    board.setAttribute("id", 'tbl');

    var identifier = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        board.appendChild(row);
        for (var j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.dataset.identifier = identifier;
            cell.innerText = identifier;
            row.appendChild(cell);
            identifier++;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(board);
}
init();
```

```css
main>table td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main id="main"></main>
```

Also, you don't need to store the coordinates of the cell, since you can calculate them from the identifier like this:

```js
row = Math.floor(identifier / GRID_SIZE);
column = identifier % GRID_SIZE;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked. is there a reason why I can't use custom properties? thanks btw about all the suggestions.

Comment: It's considered a bad practice [to modify objects you don't own](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/). In the future, the HTML standard may add a property called `identifier` to element objects.

Comment: aaaah ok it's to not have maintenance nightmares in the future, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`GRID_SIZE*i+j;`

put it inside the cell using `cell.innerHTML=GRID_SIZE*i+j;`

```js
function init(GRID_SIZE) {
  var board = document.createElement('table');
  board.setAttribute("border", 1);
  board.setAttribute("cellspacing", 0);
  board.setAttribute("id", 'tbl');

  var identifier = 0; // <-------
  for (var i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    board.appendChild(row);
    for (var j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.setAttribute('height', 20);
      cell.setAttribute('width', 20);
      cell.innerHTML = GRID_SIZE * i + j;
      cell.classList.add('col' + j, 'row' + i);
      cell.identifier = identifier; // <-------
      row.appendChild(cell);
      identifier += identifier; // <--------
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(board);
}
init(10)
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```